# Laravel blade template not showing changes on live server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project in Laravel in which I changed the master blade and the updates are not showing when I visit the site. Specifically, I added `https` to all of my assets since I am serving them over https. Since the changes are not showing, I am getting a mixed content error in the console. Here are some things that I have tried:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- Clear server cache
- Use private browser to check changes
- Use cell phone not connected to the same network since our proxy could be caching changes
- Checked the server to make sure the file did, in fact, show the changes and it does

Here is the URL in case you want to take a look: https://dericcain.com/about

For some reason, I think that someone is going to check it and it will display correctly. I feel like something is caching it but I just cannot figure out what.

Any ideas?

Comment: check if you're using a server cache , apc or opcache ,,  ??

Comment: Test if you have any syntax error in your HTML. I had this issue before.

Comment: php artisan cache:clear and php artisan view:clear solved my problem :) Well I have stopped apache2 before doing it and then restarted.

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely server related and thanks to @abdou for the heads up to search and find other sources of caching. I'm using Easyengine and it uses memcache, nginx caching and opcache.

If you are using Easyengine, here is the solution to flush all of your caches:

https://vimeo.com/122271320